# Difference between String! and String in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, null

I'm developing an android application using kotlin and the Android Studio auto completion menu is showing this (I'm elaborating a server response)

[image]

As you can see `message` and `status` are two strings, but one is the first is marked as `String!` and the other one as `String`, but I don't get the difference

I tried to check in the (java) source code and `status` is marked as `@NonNull`, while `message` does not have any annotation, but if the String can be null in this case in kotlin I should access to it using the `!!` operator and it should be marked with `?`, not with `!`, because it would be of type `String?`.

What is going on here?

Comment: either `String` or `String?`. Probably coming from Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types marked with ! come from Java and they are called `platform types`. It means that the Kotlin compiler does not know if the value can be null or not, because there were no nullability annotations found for them.

From the [official documentation:](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types)

> Null-checks are relaxed for such types, so that safety guarantees for
>   them are the same as in Java

You should be careful with these types because they can cause runtime exceptions:

> When we call methods on variables of platform types, Kotlin does not
>   issue nullability errors at compile time, but the call may fail at
>   runtime, because of a null-pointer exception or an assertion that
>   Kotlin generates to prevent nulls from propagating

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sergii's answer, Kotlin compiler supports a set of annotations allowing it to infer the correct type as you mentioned in your question. The full list is available [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations) and, at the moment, includes among the others:

- JetBrains' `@Nullable` and `@NotNull`
- Annotations provided by Android under package `android.support.annotation`

If you annotate a Java method with one of the supported annotations, then when calling that method from Kotlin you'll get "for free" the correct type, i.e., either `String` or `String?` as per your example.

If otherwise you can't edit the source code, but you know that a given method never returns `null`, then you can "force" the type you want by explicitly typing your variable (as described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types)). Example:

```
val url: String = result.checkpoint_url
```

In this way your `url` variable won't be a `String!` anymore, but it will be forced to be a `String`. Similarly, you can do the same with `val url: String? = xxx`.
Please note, though, that while the latter never fails (since it can contain both a nullable and a non-nullable string), the former can fail if `result.checkpoint_url` *actually is* `null`, and in such a case a runtime exception will be thrown.